# How to install a proper PHP ODBC driver for this SQL Server connection app

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, driver

I have been developing a PHP application that connects to a local SQL Server via php_odbc on my local environment. Today I migrated the whole code to a new server running Ubuntu 20.04 and Apache webserver. I've installed everything that seemed neccessary for me, including php_odbc (I can see ODBC in my phpinfo()).

I am connecting using "SQL Server" driver like this:

```
$connection_string = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=[my_ip];DATABASE=[my_db];CHARSET=cp1250';
$user = 'myusername';
$pass = 'mypassword';
$connection = odbc_connect( $connection_string, $user, $pass, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC );
```

It works well on my local server but it doesn't work on a new server. This server is on the same network as the SQL Server and I can ping the SQL Server IP without any trouble. I've also tried to specify the 1433 port explicitly, but no luck. I've checked the odbcinst.ini file and it seems the "SQL Server" driver is not installed. How can I install it? I am running PHP 7.4.

Thank you.

Comment: What kind error it throws?

Comment: @ArtemRusinov None unfortunately. odbc_connect only returns false on unsuccessful connection. I've tried printing odbc_error and odbc_errormsg but they are empty. But I can see driver related errors in PHP error log. `AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found, SQL state 01000 in SQLConnect in /var/www/html/[path_to_my_php].php on line 6'`

Comment: it looks like your server does not have suitable odbc driver. Try take one from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @ArtemRusinov I've installed the version 17 as suggested, I can see the driver after Apache restart in my odbcinst.ini as well, everything seems good. But the connection still doesn't work, I've changed the connection string accordingly to `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=[my_ip];PORT=1433;DATABASE=[my_db];CHARSET=cp1250` but I am getting this error in the logs: `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute, SQL state 01S00 in SQLConnect` (the error is coming from Microsoft so apparently driver is loaded, but conn.string seems OK to me.

Comment: It looks like it is finally working. I had `SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC` set as fourth parameter in my odbc_connect() call, which was required for the driver I was using on my local environment, but was messing up the connection with this new driver. Thanks